# How to add photos to iOS simulator to test working with a huge photo library?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

The default simulator comes with 5 images. Is there a way to add for example additional 100 dummy images to the simulator's photo album?

This is mainly to test the functionality of working with a huge photo library with lots of images.

Any help or guidance will be greatly helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add images to the iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441973/how-do-i-add-images-to-the-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and drop:

1. Open the Simulator
2. Navigate to the Photos.app
3. Drag and drop images, videos, GIFs, etc from your computer into the simulator
4. They'll appear in your Photos.app gallery now and you can import them into your app

Answer (score 1):

Use UIKit's [`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum?language=objc). Or use the linked answer.